# Strange behavior of Macro-expansion

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define VAL1(a,b)    a*b
#define VAL2(a,b)    a/b
#define VAL3(a,b)    ++a%b
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;
    int d = 3;
    int e = 5;

    int result = VAL2(a,d)/VAL1(e,b)+VAL3(c,d);  // result = 1
    //int result = a/d/e*b+++c%d;                // result = 0

    printf("%d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Why aren't the results of two statements the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In one case you have `+ ++` and in the other case you have `++ +`. `+ ++` and `++ +` are different streams of *tokens*. Macro pasting doesn't change tokenization because it's tokens that are pasted.

If you punch your program into a C pre-processor, you'll get this out for that line:

```
int result = a/d/e*b+ ++c%d;
```

Notice that the preprocessor had to insert a space because one is mandatory between a `+` token and a `++` token.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compile it with GCC 4.7, and the two expressions gave the same results.

If you want to see how macro will expand, you can use `cpp`, which is the C Preprossessor, and will give you the output after preprocessor expression are executed, here the output is

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;
    int d = 3;
    int e = 5;

    int result = a/d/e*b+++c%d;  
    int result2 = a/d/e*b+++c%d;  

    printf("%d %d\n", result, result2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wrong. Look more closely. It preprocesses to `int result = a/d/e*b+ ++c%d;`

Comment: I compile it by Code::Blocks with GCC 4.7.0,but the results are different!

Answer (score -1):

If you really think it is necessary to use such macros, you'll need to use parenthesis `()` to avoid side-effects:

```
#define VAL1(a,b)    ((a)*(b))
#define VAL2(a,b)    ((a)/(b))
#define VAL3(a,b)    ((++a)%(b))
```

Comment: I know it's a good habit. But I want to know why VAL2(a,d)/VAL1(e,b)+VAL3(c,d) is different from a/d/e*b+++c%d after macro expansion!