# Multiplication and division: weird output in c

Tags: c, math

I read that `*` (multiplication) has has higher presedence than `/` (division). Thus if there is an equation with both `*` and `/`, then `*` must take place first.

But I've seen a program that output something strange

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SQUARE(x) x*x

int main()
{
    float s=10, u=30, t=2, a;
    a = 2*(s-u*t)/SQUARE(t);
    printf("Result = %f", a);
    return 0;
}
```

When running this, I thought that the output would be -25, but in fact it was -100.

When I looked for the explanation it was

```
 Step 2: a = 2*(s-u*t)/SQUARE(t); becomes,

// Here SQUARE(t) is replaced by macro to t*t
=> a = 2 * (10 - 30 * 2) / t * t;

=> a = 2 * (10 - 30 * 2) / 2 * 2;

=> a = 2 * (10 - 60) / 2 * 2;

=> a = 2 * (-50) / 2 * 2 ;  

/*till here it's OK*/
/*why it divided -50 by 2 before multiplying 2*2 and -50*2 */
=> a = 2 * (-25) * 2 ;

=> a = (-50) * 2 ;

=> a = -100;
```

Can any one explain please?

Comment: Yet another reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/126fe14k.aspx

Comment: This has many duplicates, e.g [Strange behavior of Macro-expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337185/strange-behavior-of-macro-expansion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parenthesis paranoia! Your macro should be:

```
#define SQUARE(X) ((x)*(x))
```

Or else precedence rules and macro expansion will do weird things. Your macro:

```
100 / SQUARE(2)
```

will expand to:

```
100 / 2*2
```

and that is read as:

```
(100/2) * 2
```

which is 100, not 25.

Other anomaly, not in your code is if you try to square an expression:

```
SQUARE(2+2)
```

will expand to

```
2+2*2+2
```

which is `8`, not the expected `16`.

Conclusion: in macros write a lot of parentheses. Everywhere.

Comment: Not everywhere, only around macro parameters (and where they should naturally be). ;-)

Comment: @tristopia: Yeah, and around the whole expression. I was exaggerating for effect.

Answer (score 3):

Division and muliplication have the same precedence, and are thus evaluated from left to right. http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm

Answer (score 2):

It does not do what you think it does: after the step marked `/*till here it's OK*/`, the operations proceed in their regular order for multiplicative operators, i.e. left to right:

```
=> a = 2 * (-50) / 2 * 2 ;
/*till here it's OK*/
=> a = -100 / 2 * 2 ; // Division
=> a = -50 * 2 ;      // Multiplication
=> a = -100 ;         // Done
```

Your code is a perfect example of why one needs to be very careful with macros: parenthesizing macro's parameters would fix this particular problem, but some problems are simply non-fixable. For example, your macro would remain unsuitable for expressions with side effects:

```
#define SQUARE(X) ((x)*(x))
// Still not good:

int a = 2;
// Undefined behavior, because ((a++)*(a++)) uses expressions with side effects without a sequence point
int b = SQUARE(a++);
```

For this reason, you would be better off making `SQUARE` a function.